# How to instruct IBM Watson Discovery about the format of my documents?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I am trying to use the Watson Discovery service to build a virtual customer support agent. We have many documents with tons of Q and A in various formats. In the simplest case, we just have a doc, with an array of:

Q:..
A:...

Q:...
A:...

etc. When we upload these PDF files and then try to query it, it returns the full document that included the relevant answer. Is there a way to instruct Discover service, so that it will only return the relevant question and answer pair instead of the full document?

Answer (score 1):

To have Discovery return the individual relevant QA pairs, they should be split up and passed to the service as separate documents. Discovery does not have a method to split a single document on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary requirement is Q&A, you might probably look into [Retrieve-Rank](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-rank.html)

Discovery is used to deal with complex unstructured data, in your case you have data in a consistent format.

Have a look at this sample app [here](https://answer-retrieval.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=60513453706614848090642&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1485150888)