# Training IBM Watson Discovery Service for FAQ customer supporting

Tags: training-data, watson-discovery

I'm trying to build FAQs customer support agent with Watson Discovery Service and uploading FAQs documents to this service, but when I query it shows full documents content as a result.
There is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41689609/7377412) that `Question and Answer` pairs should be uploaded as a separate documents, but there are many `Question and Answer` pairs in FAQ document.
So is it possible to train Watson Discovery Service and improve results for supporting FAQ format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Discovery to split your FAQ into Question/Answer pairs automatically on ingestion, look into the Segmentation feature: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/building.html#performing-segmentation

You could also try using Passage Retrieval: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/query-parameters.html#passages

(I am an IBM Employee)